# What is the least number of roots does this equation have $x^{10} - 4x^6 + x^4- 2x -3 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> What is the least number of imaginary roots does this equation have $$x^{10} - 4x^6 + x^4- 2x -3 = 0$$

Answer is - at least four imaginary roots

I tried to use Descartes rule of signs, but since the powers are not continuously decreasing here, I cannot use it. Please tell me, if there is any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: In theory, the _exact_ number of complex roots is known (or at least knowable), so asking about the _minimum_ number of imaginary roots seems a bit strange to me. If they are asking you the minimum number you should be able to find with whatever tools you have learned, then in order to help you you have to help us a bit first. Other than Descartes' rule, what do you know about polynomials and their roots?

Comment: Why minimum? Perhaps you ommited some parameter? We can find exactly how many there are unless I am missing something..

Comment: When you say "imaginary", do you mean specifically on the imaginary axis, or are you referring to complex, non-real roots?

Comment: What do you mean by "The powers are not continuously decreasing?"  In any eventn Descartes' rule of signs is applicable.  There are at most $3$ positive roots and at most $3$ negative roots and $0$ is not a root, so there are at least $4$ non-real roots.

Comment: This polynomial has precisely zero imaginary roots, since the polynomial has exactly one non-zero odd power.

Comment: The polynomial has no repeated roots because $\gcd(f,f')=1$, so it has precisely $10$ complex roots, two of which are real.

Comment: I am referring to complex real roots. And you are right, it was asked to tell the least number of roots. To solve any other equation, I prefer taking the variables common i.e. $x^6(x^4 - 4) + x^4 - 2x - 3 = 0$. but I didn't got any useful relational from it to solve. @Arthur

Comment: "The rule states that if the terms of a single-variable polynomial with real coefficients are ordered by descending variable exponent" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs @saulspatz

Comment: Check at Wolfram Alpha: factor(x^10−4x^6+x^4−2x−3). It has two pure real roots and 8 complex.

Comment: real roots are (at least): 1.368, 1.431. This leaves 8 complex roots, they come in pairs.

Comment: @sawankumawat Yes, and the exponents are so ordered.

Comment: I don't know, what wrong I did in asking this question after trying a lot by myself, Please tell me why my question was downvoted?

Comment: Don't worry about the rating focus on the learning...

Answer (score 1):

If $x= ai$ where $a$ is real then we get $$ -a^{10}+4a^6+a^4-2ai-3=0$$

Since both real and imaginary parts are $0$ we get $a=0$ and so $-3=0$. Thus this equation has no **imaginary** solution.

Anyway, this equation has $10$ **complex** solutions!

Of course, the number of **real** solutions is most interesting to find.

Comment: Are you interested in imaginary or nonreal solutions?

Comment: I was just interested in number of complex roots

Comment: Consider an equation $m^3 - m = 0$, now put $m = ai$ now by comparison, still this equation has 0 imaginary roots, but indeed the equation has two complex roots.

Comment: No, it has 3 complex roots!

Comment: Complex roots always occurs in pairs.

Comment: No! Nonreal solutions apear in pairs. Not complex!

Comment: No I have instead upvoted your answer @Maria Mazur